# Is there anything I could read that talks about dimensionality of prime/composite numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization

Is there anything out there that talks about how primes are one dimensional numbers and composites can only be in dimensions greater than 1?

What I mean is, 4 would be a two dimensional number (2x2) same with 6 (2x3).
27 would be three dimensional (3x3x3) and so on. While primes can only be made up of themselves therefore they are one dimension.

Comment: also, if there is any reading out there. Is there anything interesting about how the different dimensional numbers interact/ any patterns that wouldn't be intuitive?

Comment: I've never heard this called dimension before.  There are lots of books patterns in the prime numbers, and a smaller but still substantial literature on how many prime factors are in a number.  If you're happy with that I can make some suggestions.  If you're looking for some other semantic tie-in with the word 'dimension', I think you're not going to find it.

Comment: The Neo-Pythagoreans, a long time ago, drew such distinctions. By the way, I do not believe we can think of $9$ as three-dimensional, but $8$ and $12$ qualify.

Comment: The lattice of factors for a square-free integer (i.e., a product of unique primes, none repeated) is isomorphic to the face lattice of a simplex. So it's possible to label the faces of a $2$-dimensional simplex (triangle) with divisors of $30$ in a nicely geometric way, vertices labeled with $2, 3$, and $5$, and convex hull of a set of vertices is labeled the least common multiple of those numbers (so the intersection of faces is the gcd). A three dimensional simplex (tetrahedron) would work for something like $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 210$, but repeated primes don't play nicely.

Comment: yes i fixed 9 to 27, my bad on the editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant that 27 would be "three dimensional" but 9 would be "two dimensional", then the "dimension" of a number $n$ is the total number of prime factors, denoted $\Omega(n)$ (often read "big omega"). It is not usually called the dimension of a number, but if you really like to think geometrically, you can think about it as the greatest dimension in which the number is the "[hypervolume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_(measure_theory))" of [a hyperrectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle) with side lengths greater than 1.

See the following links for some information.

- https://oeis.org/A001222
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor#Omega_functions
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#.CE.A9.28n.29.2C_.CF.89.28n.29.2C_.CE.BDp.28n.29_.E2.80.93_prime_power_decomposition

Answer (score 1):

This is something I'm actively curious about and I do have some experience with working with modular building blocks. If you view primes on the number line it's one dimension, and of course there are multiple ways to graph prime distributions on the plane in two dimensions. In three dimensions you could consider arithmetic progressions and the inverse square law. Carl Sagan famously considered this as a cuboid monolith while consulting on cinematic metaphors used in the sci fi film 2001:A Space Odyssey. The first three primes squared. Much more than a metaphor?
https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/.../mrwatkin/isoc/2001.htm....